# Cannot log into mysql after invoking mysql from shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, password, shell-scripting

(My first question here, so if I am flouting any conventions, I apologize in advance!)

This is my first attempt at creating a shell script. I am trying to create new databases and users and passwords by specifying them at the command line, along with the shell script. My root username and password are specified within the shell script.
Here is my shell script which does this:

> #! /bin/sh
>
> # creates tables
>
> masteruser="root"
>
> masterpassword="dumbpassword"
>
> # require one argument on the command line
>
> if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
>
> ```
> echo "Usage: createdb.sh dbname dbuser dbpassword";
> exit 1;
> ```
>
> fi
>
> dbname="$1"
>
> dbuser="$2"
>
> dbpassword="$3"
>
> #echo $dbname
>
> #echo $dbuser
>
> #echo $dbpassword
>
> mysql -u "$masteruser" -p"$masterpassword"  <<EOF
>
> create database $1; grant all on $1.* to '$2' identified by '$3';
>
> flush privileges
>
> EOF

I am running this from commandline like this:

> ./shellscriptname.sh newdbname newdbuser newdbpassword

After running this script (which creates databases successfully) multiple times, when I try to connect, this happens:

> # mysql --user root --password dumbpassword
>
> Enter password: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'dumbpassword'

I don't know why this is happening. (Note: there is no semicolon after flush privileges)

Why is it no longer working? I am curious, since I cannot find any problems with my script.
Neither is this working:

> mysql -u root -p dumbpassword

I am more interested in finding out why this happened, than in solving the issue. So I thought I will ask the gurus here!

Comment: Why in your script are you assigning $1 to dbname, etc then reusing $1? In your create line, use `create database ${dbname}; grant all on ${dbname}.* to '${dbuser}' identified by '${dbpassword}'`. Also, you don't need to use `flush privileges` after the grant statement. You only need to do that if you modify the mysql.* tables directly.

Comment: I will do that. Still I don't know why this is happening though?

Answer (score 2):

You should use following

```
mysql --user root --password=dumbpassword
```

or

```
mysql -u root -pdumbpassword
```

Note that there is no space between -p/--password and password itself.

Answer (score -1):

The correct format for logging in to mysql is:

```
mysql -u username -p mydbname
```

This allows you to log in to the database "mydbname". Instead you have passed the password as the database name, so mySQL is telling you that it cannot find the database "dumbpassword"

Try this:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

This will allow you to login in to mysql after prompting for the password, and then you can choose the database with :

```
use mydbname
```

If you run mysql without the u/p switches, it will pick up the username and password from the current context.

Comment: My answer is not incorrect.

Comment: How does it pick up the password from the currently logged in user?